# oauth architecture with mobile and custom backend

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth

I don't quite understand how oauth 2.0 works with a mobile app and a backend.

Say I have a mobile app that users login with facebook. Once they login, I would like them to make requests to my backend. How does my backend know about the users who login? This was the flow I had in mind:

```
iOS -> facebook
iOS <- facebook (send token back to iOS)
iOS -> my backend (store token in db)
iOS <-> my backend
```

Is this the correct flow or should I be requesting login like this:

```
iOS -> my backend -> facebook
       my backend <- facebook(token)
iOS <-> mybackend
```

Is there a good tutorial / explanation on how oauth works in this case?